# Keep D3 objects size constant on Map while zoom in/out

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I am following the example from http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/raw/5193723/

The cirles drawn in the example increases in size when zoomed-in. I am not able to figure out a way in which the circles' size can be kept same.

Any ideas?

**Edit1**: Any ideas on how to keep Pie arc constant in radii. I have figured out the the way to keep circles to constant radius as below:

```
            g1.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", 200)
                .attr("cy", 200)
                .attr("r", 10)
                .style("fill", "red");

        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {

                g1.selectAll("circle")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate.join(",") + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
                    .attr("r", function(d) {
                        return 10/d3.event.scale;
                    });
            });
```

Similarly I have arcs of pie chart, the size of which I wish to maintain at zoom:

```
                    var r = 4;
                    var p = Math.PI * 2;

                    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(r - 2)
                        .outerRadius(r - 1)
                        .startAngle(0)
                        .endAngle(p * d.value1);
                    var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(r - 3)
                        .outerRadius(r - 2)
                        .startAngle(0)
                        .endAngle(p * d.value2);

                   var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                        .center([0, 5])
                        .scale(200)

                    var translate = "translate(" + projection([77, 13])[0] + ", " + projection([77, 13])[1] + ")";
                    g.append("path")
                        .attr("d", arc)
                        .attr("fill", "maroon")
                        .attr("transform", translate);
                    g.append("path")
                        .attr("d", arc2)
                        .attr("fill", "green")
                        .attr("transform", translate);
```

Any suggestions on how to keep the arc type paths to maintain same size?

Comment: Zoom the projection, rather than the SVG.  This will keep everything else on your SVG the same.  See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340 for an example.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to add some additional processing in the zoom event handler. Set the circle's radii to be their nominal value (5) divided by the zoom factor (`zoom.scale()`). That way, when the zoom scaling is applied the result will be a constant apparent size. Something like:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function() {
        g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
            d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        g.selectAll("circle")
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection))
            .attr("r", 5/zoom.scale());
        g.selectAll("path")  
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection)); 
    });
```

Comment: @stephan, thanks for the reply. Actually I have worked out the approach you suggested.

Comment: @stephan, Now my problem is not limited to circles, but to arcs of pie. See the Edited section of my question.