# retain pie chart size when user zoom using d3js and topojson

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

JSfiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/aumy37nc/1/

I have plotted world map with pie charts on top of it. I want to retain the pie chart when user zooms the map. Right now pie chart gets scaled with the map when the user zooms.

Also tried the solution from the link below but no luck.

```
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460534/keep-d3-objects-size-constant-on-map-while-zoom-in-out'
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to refactor this and create a `drawPieChart` method, then trigger this on the zoom event.. Also a cleaner jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aumy37nc/1/

Comment: @Pogrindis, Thanks. I tried what you suggested but it din't work. Created function for drawingPieChart and triggering that function on zoom. Any other workaround.